# Pure bash program for auto-filling a template file with ENV variables

Tags: bash

### Goal of Program

Consider a template file `template.txt` with double brace variables, intended to be replaced by values:

```
hello there {{ MY_VAR1 }}
some other stuff
some other stuff
foo: {{ MY_VAR2 }}
{{ MY_VAR2 }} is the value of MY_VAR2
```

and assume you have defined and exported those variables:

```
export MY_VAR1=val1
export MY_VAR2=val2
```

we want a script `fill_template` such that `fill_template template.txt` produces:

```
hello there val1
some other stuff
some other stuff
foo: val2
val2 is the value of MY_VAR2
```

and which gives an appropriate error message if any of the required template variables are not defined.

### Code for review

Here is working code for `fill_template`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -f $1 ]]; then
  >&2 echo "Usage: $0 <filename>"
  exit 1
fi

# Gather all the required template variables

vars=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    vars+=( "$line" )
done < <( awk 'match($0, /{{ (.*) }}/, a) { print a[1] }' "$1" | sort -u )

# Verify that all template variables are set and exported

missing=()
for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
  if [[ -z ${!var+x} ]]; then
    missing+=( "$var" )
  fi
done

if [[ ${#missing[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
  >&2 echo "The following required variables have not been set and exported:"
  for var in "${missing[@]}"; do
    >&2 echo "${var}"
  done
  exit 1
fi

# Dynamically construct the sed cmd to do the replacement

sed_cmd=
for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
  sed_cmd+="s/\\{\\{ *${var} *}}/${!var}/g;"
done

sed -E "${sed_cmd}" "$1"
```

### Notes

- All comments welcome, from the high-level approach to nitpicks.
- Currently we assume there will be only one `{{ TEMPLATE_VAR }}` per line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Make the template variable name extraction more strict

The Awk command extracts the template variable names using the pattern `/{{ (.*) }}/`.
This leaves some room to human errors.
For example excess whitespace, as in `{{  MY_VAR   }}`.
This can be especially frustrating for trailing whitespace, which will be invisible when printing the list of missing variables.
I think it would be good to strip whitespaces after `{{` and before `}}`.

But that's not quite enough. Consider such line in the input:

> ```
> hello there {{ MY_VAR1 }} foo bar {{ baz }}
> ```

Although using multiple variables is explicitly unsupported,
this blows up in the face of the user in a nasty way:

> ```
> $ MY_VAR1=foo/bar/bazo MY_VAR2=bar bash script.sh input.txt
> a.sh: line 19: MY_VAR1 }} foo bar {{ baz: bad substitution
> a.sh: line 33: MY_VAR1 }} foo bar {{ baz: bad substitution
> hello there {{ MY_VAR1 }} foo bar {{ baz }}
> some other stuff
> some other stuff
> foo: {{ MY_VAR2 }}
> {{ MY_VAR2 }} is the value of MY_VAR2
> ```

The error messages are unfortunately incomprehensible.

Since the template variable names are expected to take values from shell variables,
it would make sense to enforce a stricter pattern.

Even if the script is not intended to handle sophisticated scenarios,
I think it should handle such user mistakes more gracefully.

#### Consistency

The Sed command replacing template variable names with values uses the pattern `\\{\\{ *${var} *}}`.
This is not consistent with the one in the Awk command,
because of stripping the whitespace.
As mentioned earlier, I would adjust the Awk command to make it consistent.

#### Error handling

In the example above with a user mistake,
the script continued to execute even after the error.
To catch such issues and terminate the program early I recommend adding this line at the very beginning:

```
set -euo pipefail
```

#### Beware of some gotchas

`/` in the template variable names and values will break the Sed command.

As for the names, a more strict handling as mentioned earlier will prevent this issue.

As for the values, `/` appearing in the values doesn't sound too crazy,
because I can easily imagine wanting to insert path strings.
So I think it's a legitimate concern that would be good to address.

#### Usability

The limitation to one template variable per line seems a bit artificial.

Currently the script fails fast when the user mistakenly tries to use multiple per line, that's a good behavior to preserve.
(I'm pointing this out because if you simply enforce more stricter checking on the name patterns, this fail-fast behavior may no longer be the case.
And if I had to choose between cryptic failures, and quietly ignored missed template variables, I would prefer cryptic failures.)

Comment: Janos, great comments.  Tyvm.  I'm going to make the suggested changes and then repost the revised version.  As a side note, I was curious what you thought of [this warning against set -e](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- not in relation to my script, but just in general.

Comment: @Jonah my personal recommendation is to go ahead and use `set -e`, but beware of possible gotchas, *and* add your own error checking too ;-)